# Changing Timezone of Carbon Object

Tags: php, timezone, php-carbon

I am taking a string which I am parsing with Carbon and specifying the timezone at UTC. Then, I am switching the timezone to America/Denver and outputting a formatted string and the time value does not change. What am I doing wrong? I have searched all over and everything I have read shows me that this should work.

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2018-08-19 10:43:15', 'UTC');
Log::info($date->timezone->getName());
Log::info($date->format('n/j/y g:i A'));

$date->setTimezone('America/Denver');

Log::info($date->timezone->getName());
Log::info($date->format('n/j/y g:i A'));
```

My log returns:

```
[2018-08-19 11:23:17] local.INFO: UTC  
[2018-08-19 11:23:17] local.INFO: 8/19/18 10:43 AM  
[2018-08-19 11:23:17] local.INFO: America/Denver  
[2018-08-19 11:23:17] local.INFO: 8/19/18 10:43 AM
```

Comment: Your code changes the time for me, I'm on Europe/London. Does this return true or false: `var_dump(date_default_timezone_set('UTC'));`

Comment: It returns as true. I have the default timezone of the server and PHP set to UTC so that when I insert values into my mysql database that they will be stored as UTC. What I'm trying to do is take a value returned from my database in UTC and then convert it to a local timezone.

Comment: your code above showed 6 hours diff on mine, the only change I made was to dump the values instead of logging. Other than you var_dump them just to eliminate that, I can't think I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I have also tried `$date->setTimezone('America/Denver')->format('n/j/y g:i A');` and it also returns the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no code error. This is a CentOS 7 server. When I changed my timezone I  copied the UTC file to /etc/localtime overwriting the currently symlinked America/Denver file in /usr/shared/zoneinfo. The proper procedure is to delete the symlink of /etc/localtime and recreate it pointing to the correct timezone file. Because my America/Denver file had been overwritten by the UTC file then the server was returning America/Denver times as UTC.

My solution was the copy the America/Denver file from another server and overwrite my broken America/Denver file. This resolved my problem.